# Runtime datatable update error

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview with a checkbox column. When I click(check/Uncheck) on checkbox field as random, two other fields in corrensponding row should be added OR removed in a datatable (declared runtime).

So that I can do some procedures with data in the datatable.
For that I have declared a datatable as global.

Now the problem is, each time when I click on a checkbox, a simple mouse scrolling is required to update datatable, OR a click needed in the new datagridview which is showing values in the datatable.

My code given below,

global declaration:  Public PaymentTable As DataTable

```
Private Sub ShowOrdersFrm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataBind()
    Me.DGVOrders.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.GhostWhite
    Me.DGVOrders.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.PaleGoldenrod
    PaymentTable = New DataTable()
    PaymentTable.Columns.Add("RowId", GetType(Integer))
    PaymentTable.Columns.Add("Amount", GetType(Decimal))

End Sub
Private Sub DataBind()
    DGVOrders.DataSource = Nothing
    DGVOrders.Columns.Clear()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    con.Open()
    With cmd
        .Connection = con
        .CommandText = "select * from VIEW_PAYMENTS_DUES_BYORDER where CustCode='" & CustCode & "' order by OrderNo DESC"
    End With
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    da.Fill(dt)
    BindingSource1.DataSource = dt
    DGVOrders.DataSource = BindingSource1
    DGVOrders.ClearSelection()
    con.Close()
    DGVOrders.Columns(0).Visible = False
    DGVOrders.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Order No"
    DGVOrders.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Cust Code"
    DGVOrders.Columns(3).HeaderText = "Name"
    DGVOrders.Columns(4).HeaderText = "Order Date"
    DGVOrders.Columns(5).HeaderText = "Order Price"
    DGVOrders.Columns(6).HeaderText = "Total Payment"
    DGVOrders.Columns(7).HeaderText = "Dues"
    For i = 0 To DGVOrders.RowCount - 1
        If DGVOrders.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value > 0 Then
            DGVOrders.Rows(i).Cells(7).Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        Else
            DGVOrders.Rows(i).Cells(7).Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
        End If
     Next
    ' CHECK BOX
    Dim colmnchk As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
    colmnchk.DataPropertyName = "chkSelect"
    colmnchk.HeaderText = "SELECT"
    colmnchk.Name = "chkSelect"
    DGVOrders.Columns.Add(colmnchk)
    For i = 0 To DGVOrders.RowCount - 1

    Next
    'CHECK BOX END
End Sub

Private Sub DGVOrders_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGVOrders.CellValueChanged
        If DGVOrders.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "chkSelect" Then
            Dim checkCell As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = _
           CType(DGVOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("chkSelect"),  _
           DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
            If checkCell.Value = True Then
               PaymentTable.Rows.Add(DGVOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value, DGVOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(7).Value)

         Else

            Dim toRemoveID As Integer = DGVOrders.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
            For i = 0 To PaymentTable.Rows.Count - 1
                If PaymentTable.Rows(i).Item(0) = toRemoveID Then
                    PaymentTable.Rows(i).Delete()

                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next
        End If
        DataGridView1.DataSource = PaymentTable
    End If
End Sub
```

Can sombody to solve the issue, or is there any other good method if my code is wrong ?

Comment: That event works for me without having to move off the cell.  Is `chkSelect` a bound or unbound column?

Comment: I am confused with the term 'bound' column, anyway I have declared a new column to gridview by this code:  Dim colmnchk As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
        colmnchk.DataPropertyName = "chkSelect"
        colmnchk.HeaderText = "SELECT"
        colmnchk.Name = "chkSelect".  Hope you got answer

Comment: Bound means it is tied to your data source (from the database).  It looks like it is Unbound and is only present in the grid.  Please edit your question and post the entire code block for adding the checkbox column.

Comment: I have provided an answer which is consistent with your method for creating the columns.  Please check it out.

Comment: Thanks, I have checked it, but nothing showing as a result, no changes to see in datatable when i use this event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a different event like `CellContentClick` and testing for the `ColumnIndex`.  The drawback with this is the event will fire whenever you click on any cell.

```
  Private Sub DGVOrders_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGVOrders.CellContentClick
    'Only interested in the CheckBox column
    If e.ColumnIndex = colmnchk.Index Then
      Debug.WriteLine("In DGVOrders_CellContentClick for the checkbox")
    End If
  End Sub
```

Comment: I have checked it, but nothing showing as a result, no changes to see in datatable when i use this event

Comment: This code overcomes the issue you stated as "Now the problem is, each time when I click on a checkbox, a simple mouse scrolling is required to update datatable, OR a click needed in the new datagridview which is showing values in the datatable."   This code will execute without having to perform scrolling or moving to another row.   Did you also want something else because that is not clear in your question

Comment: I think my question has some mistakes..What I want is, when I click on a checkbox, 2 fields in same row needs to be added in to a datatable, Current issue  is, if I clicked a first checkbox, datable doesnot update same time, it update only the time when click on a second checkbox or after a mouse scroll.

Comment: The code I gave you solves the second part.  Have you added the code you already have in `DGVOrders_CellValueChanged` to the procedure I gave you?

Comment: I tried to add, but there is an error in colmnchk.Index (showing as not declared). What do you mean by this ? is it a column name ?

Comment: `colmnchk.Index` is the 0-based index number of the column in the grid.  It can be compared against `e.ColumnIndex` so that you can verify that it is actually the checkbox column that was clicked.  This method is better than hard-coding column index numbers.  Move this line up to be a class level declaration:  `Dim colmnchk As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`

Comment: I tried with your code, debug message shows only after next checkbox click or mouse scroll

Comment: Did you copy/paste the code?  I find it impossible that this is happening.  The `CellContentClick` does not have anything to do with closing the edit (moving to another cell or row)

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, I tried this code in CellValueChanged. Just now i tried it in CellContentClick event, now the debug message showing correctly, but datatable is empty